# How to show/hide particular section in tableview with customised two cells

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, xcode, uitableview

I have to show tableview with two sections based on flag value. Based on flag value I have to show/hide first section.
First section has only one row and static customised cell which will show always same data.
And second section is another customised cell, Which is dynamic rows shows from server data.
I need to show Second section is always. First section based on flag I have to show or hide.
How to handle this?

Here is my code

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.registerCells()
    }

    func registerCells(){

        self.DetailsTableview.register(RadioButtonTableViewCell.nib, forCellReuseIdentifier: RadioButtonTableViewCell.identifier)
        if flagValue == true {
            self.DetailsTableview.register(UPPercentageCell.nib, forCellReuseIdentifier: PercentageCell.identifier)
        }
}

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        if flagValue == true {
            return 2
        }
        return 1
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        if flagValue == true {
            return 20
        }
        return 40
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        
        if flagValue == true {
            if section == 0 {
                return 1
            } else {
                return self.response?.data?.count ?? 0
            }
        }
        return self.response?.data?.count ?? 0
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        
        if flagValue == true {
            if indexPath.section == 0 {
                let percentagecell: PercentageCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "PercentageCell", for: indexPath) as! UPPercentageCell
                percentagecell.percentage = "20" //some dynamic value
                percentagecell.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
                return percentagecell
            } else {
                let cell: RadioButtonTableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "RadioButtonTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! RadioButtonTableViewCell
                cell.displayDataToUI(title: response?.data?[indexPath.row] ?? "", currentIndexpath: indexPath, selectedIndexpath: selectedIndexpath ?? IndexPath())
                cell.radioButtonClicked = {
                    [weak self] (indexpath) in
                    self?.saveButton.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
                    self?.reloadTableviewFromSelectedIndexpath(indexpath: indexpath)
                }
                return cell
            }
            
        } else {
            let cell: RadioButtonTableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "RadioButtonTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! RadioButtonTableViewCell
                cell.displayDataToUI(title: response?.data?[indexPath.row] ?? "", currentIndexpath: indexPath, selectedIndexpath: selectedIndexpath ?? IndexPath())
                cell.radioButtonClicked = {
                    [weak self] (indexpath) in
                    self?.saveButton.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
                    self?.reloadTableviewFromSelectedIndexpath(indexpath: indexpath)
                }
                return cell
        }
        return UITableViewCell()
    }
```

Is there any better approach to achieve this?

Highly appreciate your valuable suggestions.

Comment: Maybe you should try to model your dataSource as `[[itemCells]]` with this you can remove complete sections by modifying this array of arrays were each of inner arrays are a section, and you can remove add or remove easily additionally your `numberOfRowsInSection` and your `numberOfSections` logic will be dramatically decreased and your code readability/maintainability  will be better.

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is fine, but you can simplify things a bit with fewer if/else blocks...

First:

```
func registerCells(){
    self.DetailsTableview.register(RadioButtonTableViewCell.nib, forCellReuseIdentifier: RadioButtonTableViewCell.identifier)
    // doesn't hurt to go ahead and register both cell classes for reuse
    self.DetailsTableview.register(UPPercentageCell.nib, forCellReuseIdentifier: PercentageCell.identifier)
}
```

next, just a more compact way of writing it:

```
override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return flagValue ? 2 : 1
}
```

and:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    // this will only be true if
    //  section is 0
    //  AND
    //  flagValue is true
    if section == 0 && flagValue {
        return 1
    }

    //  whether we're in section 0 WITHOUT the "top" section, or
    //  we're in section 1 WITH the "top" section
    return self.response?.data?.count ?? 0

}
```

and:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    
    // this will only be true if
    //  section is 0
    //  AND
    //  flagValue is true
    if indexPath.section == 0 && flagValue {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: UPPercentageCell.identifier, for: indexPath) as! UPPercentageCell
        cell.percentage = "20" //some dynamic value
        cell.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
        return cell
    }
    
    // we want to display the same cells from the same data array
    //  whether we're in section 0 WITHOUT the "top" section, or
    //  we're in section 1 WITH the "top" section
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: RadioButtonTableViewCell.identifier, for: indexPath) as! RadioButtonTableViewCell

    cell.displayDataToUI(title: response?.data?[indexPath.row] ?? "", currentIndexpath: indexPath, selectedIndexpath: selectedIndexpath ?? IndexPath())
    cell.radioButtonClicked = {
        [weak self] (indexpath) in
        self?.saveButton.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        self?.reloadTableviewFromSelectedIndexpath(indexpath: indexpath)
    }

    return cell
}
```